# Adding a site column and add it to a content type from PowerShell issue

Tags: content-type, powershell, field-definition

Within a PS script, I'm trying to add a site column and add this column to a custom content type.

Here is my script :

```
add-pssnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -EA 0

function AddFieldToContentType([Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb] $web, [string]$contentTypeName, [string]$xmlSchema)
{

    $fieldName = $web.Fields.AddFieldAsXml($xmlSchema)
    $web.Update()

    $field = $web.Fields[$fieldName]
    $ct = $web.AvailableContentTypes[$contentTypeName]
    $link = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldLink $field
    $ct.FieldLinks.Add($link)
    $ct.Update($true)


}

[Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb]$web = get-spweb -Identity http://somewhere
[xml]$xml = 'my field schema truncated for readability'

AddFieldToContentType $web "my content type name" $xml
```

This fails at the line `$ct.Update($true)` with this error :

> Exception calling "Update" with "1" argument(s): "The collection cannot be modified."

What's wrong with this code ?

Thanks

Answer (score 20, accepted):

AvailableContentTypes is readonly, so you need to use ContentTypes instead.

```
$field = $web.Fields[$fieldName]
$ct = $web.ContentTypes[$contentTypeName]
$link = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldLink $field
$ct.FieldLinks.Add($link)
$ct.Update($true)
```

Comment: To add to this, [AvailableContentTypes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.availablecontenttypes.aspx) is read only because it is a collection from the current scope, including those of the current website, as well as any parent websites

Comment: this solved the problem, hovewer, I don't understand the cause, as I'm not changing the content type collection, but the content type itself

Comment: The Update() method must be looking at the collection that the content type is in and using that in some way. It follows since you can't create a new content type and call Update() without first adding it to a collection - a list or web. AvailableContentTypes gathers them up into a collection for you, but it doesn't give you the collection for the specific web.

Comment: I get almost this exact same problem:
 
- **$ct.update($true)** produces an "Access Denied" error, although it does add the Site Column to the Content Type.

- however, **$ct.update($false)** works without a hitch.

- **not only that**, but in both cases, the "update all columns which use this column" is set to Yes. **I've no idea why it acts this way**.