# Can we add Site Column to All Content Types?

Tags: content-type, site-column

Like OOB,

Can we add Site Column to All Content Types using server object model?

Thanks

Comment: Yes you can, check this,http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/15692/adding-a-site-column-and-add-it-to-a-content-type-from-powershell-issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This

```
   SPList currentList = currentWeb.Lists["DocLib"];
   SPField newField = currentList.Fields.CreateNewField(SPFieldType.Text.ToString(), "New Field2");
   currentList.Fields.AddFieldAsXml(newField.SchemaXml, true, SPAddFieldOptions.AddToAllContentTypes);
   currentList.Update();
```